# Life in cybersecurity: How do I get there?

Tags: professional-education, defense

I am 17 years old and my ultimate job goal is a cyber security professional. I have been extensively studying TCP/IP, along with all other subjects in the CompTIA Network+ certification which I hope to obtain soon. I'm very familiar with tools such as OpenVAS, Wireshark, nmap, ect and I'm currently learning Python, and can write bash scripts. My question is what is what are jobs such as network security auditor or cyber security engineer like? and what things should be studied to start on this career path. Also just general information about working in the IT field would be welcomed.

Comment: Go to a school with a information security emphasis is Computer Science would be a good place to start.  For example, check out http://www.suu.edu/prostu/majors/issecurity-aas.html .  You will not only need to know the programs but in-depth how they work and not wholly rely on tools to do your job.  A fun test could be trying to exploit an old Ruby on Rails site (just create a mock up) that has the XML vulnerability and see if you can do it without relying on pre-programmed stuff (it's not that hard to exploit on the right rails version).  Also note, this question is too broad/opinion based.

Comment: This is too broad to be answered here. Most IT Sec pros would be happy to talk to you if you reached out to them in person.

Comment: Thanks guys, I never thought of exploiting ruby on rails, sounds like a good start. I'm familiar with exploiting XSS and SQL injection vulnerabilities, I have little experience with Ruby, and XML. Worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most careers within cyber security, which may also be known as information assurance (IA), usually require the Certified Information System Security Professional (CISSP) certification from the International Information Systems Security Certification Consortium (ISC)2. [[https://www.isc2.org/cissp/default.aspx]](https://www.isc2.org/cissp/default.aspx%5d)

Cyber security isn't just about knowing the technical side of everything, you have to understand the management side such as risk assessments, business continuity, disaster recovery etc. I know that's covered in the Security+ but the CISSP is a lot harder than the Security+ exam.

I personally went to university. I'm currently in my final year of BSc(Hons) Information System Security. By doing this I learnt a lot more than just reading through books. I think if you want to pursue the CISSP, this may be one of the best avenues. I think most companies or organisation dealing with cyber security or information assurance prefer their candidates have a degree. Follow this up with a Security+ and you have a good chance. Then work towards the CISSP.

To get the CISSP you need to pass the exam as well as have 5 years experience. Obviously this is evil for students and graduates so we work towards the Associate of ISC2 certificate. It basically means that you've passed the exam and are now just acquiring the experience.

That said, I know of other avenues. One is the military (but most aren't to keen on this). Another is apprenticeships through agencies such as GHCQ [[https://www.sis.gov.uk/careers/working-for-us/technical-apprenticeship.html]](https://www.sis.gov.uk/careers/working-for-us/technical-apprenticeship.html%5d)

That's all I can think up at the moment, hope it helps :D

Comment: seconding "Cyber security isn't just about knowing the technical side of everything"  

There is a huge physiological side, you need to know how people think

Answer (score 0):

go offensive.. utilize defcon.org. Get the books mentioned there & read them at least twice. Begin with the foundations.. TCP/IP, Computer Architecture, Packet Analysis, Web Applications, DBMS, Web Servers.. Get the presentations from BlackHat and Defcon conferences.

Getting your hands dirty with coding & scripting would be helpful as well. Being auditor is lame, go deep go technical.. In my humble opinion, Penetration Tester, Network Security Engineer or Web application security engineer are the careers to dive into.. Good luck!

Rgds.